# How to make loop wait until button is clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, wait

I'm working on a mathematical game that gives 10 different adding questions one by one. Those questions are displayed on the label and you can answer it by writing into a text box and clicking submit. I'm stuck with answering part, particularly with loop waiting until I press a button.

From looking it up, I found a method to make it as a new event, but I didn't get how I can make my loop wait for that event to continue

My code looks like this

```
int Between = 1;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (Between == 1)
            {
                int num1 = rnd.Next(1, 11); // 1-10
                int num2 = rnd.Next(1, 11); // 1-10
                string number1 = num1.ToString();
                string number2 = num2.ToString();
                kusimus.Text = number1 + " + " + number2;
            }
```

I need to add waiting after `kusimus.Text = number1 + " + " + number2;`. Reading the text box isn't yet added cause it wouldn't have use without button, so it aint included. "between" ain't completed eiter, so that's why i have if with int of it right before it

Comment: The UI loops for you, you don't have to. Just add the answer checking code in the button-click handler.

Comment: Why would you need a loop? Just put the code you want to run after the button is pressed into the click event handler.

Comment: loop is to do 10 questions at the time

Comment: In the click handler, you can update the label to show the next question, no need to loop.

Comment: So count how many times you've asked a question and stop at the magic number.

Comment: thank you, got it done now. answer with same info would be appreciated, wanna close it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ask a total of 10 questions, one at a time, you don't need to use a loop and wait within it. You can simply use the button click event to check the answer and update the question label.

Move `Between` and `rnd` to be class members, so you can access them in multiple methods. Alongside these, create two integers to store the current correct answer, and how many questions have been asked.

For my answer, I used these names:

```
private int Between = 1;
private Random rnd = new Random();
private int questionsAsked = 0;
private int currentAnswer = 0;
```

Update the label for the first question in the form's constructor, like so.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Get two random numbers
    int num1 = rnd.Next(1, 11); // 1-10
    int num2 = rnd.Next(1, 11); // 1-10

    // Save the answer.
    currentAnswer = num1 + num2;

    // Update the label.
    kusimus.Text = String.Format("{0} + {1}", num1, num2);

    // Keep track of how many questions have been asked.
    questionsAsked++;
}
```

Then do much of the same in the click event, including answer checking.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // We've already asked ten questions, don't do anything else.
    if (questionsAsked > 10) return;

    // If the user entered a valid integer into the text box
    int answer;
    if (int.TryParse(txtBoxAnswer.Text, out answer))
    {
        // Implement Between if still needed.
        if (Between == 1)
        {
            if (answer == currentAnswer)
            {
                // the answer is correct.
            }
            else
            {
                // the answer is incorrect
            }

            int num1 = rnd.Next(1, 11); // 1-10
            int num2 = rnd.Next(1, 11); // 1-10

            currentAnswer = num1 + num2;

            kusimus.Text = String.Format("{0} + {1}", num1, num2);
        }

        // We've asked another question.
        questionsAsked++;

        if (questionsAsked > 10)
        {
            // User has answered last question, do something?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you place it in the button click event it will work and fire when you click the button.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int between = 1;
    Random rnd = new Random();

    //This loop is pointless since there's only one number that can use it.
    //However; I've left it as it incase you're needing it for another reason.
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (between == 1)
        {
            int num1 = rnd.Next(1, 11); // 1-10
            int num2 = rnd.Next(1, 11); // 1-10
            string number1 = num1.ToString();
            string number2 = num2.ToString();
            kusimus.Text = number1 + " + " + number2;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, here's something to note also just FYI:

```
/* If the work is a loop, string manipulation, or anything that may require more than 100ms of work
* then I suggest doing it asynchronously. Hopefully this helps.
* If it's confusing or you need more comments to explain what's going on let me know.
* Don't worry about the work being done... I just tried to keep it as similar as I could to your question
* and still make it useful for the example. 
* Note: This is WPF so the Textblock works like this but it should be RichTextBox for WinForms and button will just be button.Enabled = true : false */
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    button1.IsEnabled = false;
    textblock1.Text = string.Empty;

    var between = 1;
    Random rnd = new Random();

    var randomText = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            if (between == 1)
            {
                int num1 = rnd.Next(1, 11); // 1-10
                int num2 = rnd.Next(1, 11); // 1-10
                string number1 = num1.ToString();
                string number2 = num2.ToString();
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(number1 + " + " + number2);
            }
        }
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    });

    textblock1.Text = randomText;
    button1.IsEnabled = true;
}
```